# How to turn a list inside out?

Tags: r, radix, purrr

I've got a following list:

```
> list(c(3, 4, 5, 8), c(2, 6, 9, 10), c(1, 7))
[[1]]
[1] 3 4 5 8

[[2]]
[1]  2  6  9 10

[[3]]
[1] 1 7
```

So we can say that 3 belongs to group 1, 6 belongs to group 2, 7 belongs to group 3 and so on. I need a reverse mapping, i.e. to every number I want to have a group id that it belongs to (see expected output):

```
> list(3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2)
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 1

[[4]]
[1] 1

[[5]]
[1] 1

[[6]]
[1] 2

[[7]]
[1] 3

[[8]]
[1] 1

[[9]]
[1] 2

[[10]]
[1] 2
```

I thought `purrr::transpose` should do the job but it doesn't exactly do what I intend, is it? How can it be done?

PS. Ultimately, I need just a vector of a form: `3 2 1 1 1 2 3 1 2 2`, but having above I think `unlist()` is enough to convert.

Comment: My apologies but I can't make out how  to get `3 2 1 1 1 2 3 1 2 2` from given input, Its atleast not clear to me. Thanks

Comment: @PKumar: 1 is in group 3, 2 is in group 2, 3 is in group 1, 4 is in group 1, 5 is in group 1 ...

Comment: We start from 1 and see which group 1 belongs to - we can see it's in 3rd group, namely 3rd element of a list. Then we go with 2:10 and check the same.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base solution ...

```
list <- list(c(3, 4, 5, 8), c(2, 6, 9, 10), c(1, 7))

rep(1:length(list), sapply(list, length))[order(unlist(list))]
```

Comment: Nice solution, you could fully vectorize this using `rep(seq_along(l), lengths(l))[order(unlist(l))]` (not sure what you are using `as.numeric` for).

Comment: Regarding "doesn't exactly answer my main question with list converting inside-out" I think you need to clarify your question. The way you describe and present your desired result it seems like you simply want to get the list index for each value (whih this and other answers achieve). I fail to see the 'inside-out' part ;)

Comment: @DavidArenburg Good point (original solution was a bit longer, so this was just noise left over ;-))

Answer (score 2):

Can I suggest an old-fashioned loop:

```
# your list
x <- list(c(3, 4, 5, 8), c(2, 6, 9, 10), c(1, 7))
# the data in the list as vector
num <- unlist( x )
# the variable that will be the position vector
pos <- NULL

# loop through the possible position, see which number it contains
# find which "group it belongs to, and add that finding to the position vector
for( i in 1:length( num ) )
    for( j in  1:length( x ) )
        if( i %in% x[[j]] ) pos <- c( pos, j )

pos
[1] 3 2 1 1 1 2 3 1 2 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(wrapr)

list(c(3, 4, 5, 8), c(2, 6, 9, 10), c(1, 7)) %.>%
  tibble(x = .) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  arrange(x) %$%
  set_names(rn, x) %>%
  as.list()
```

Comment: Is the 5th line a mistake `%.>%`?

Comment: No. It's a pipe from `wrapr` package.

Comment: Why do you use `%.>%` in wrapr additionally instead of using `%>%` in tidyverse? They will get the same outcome in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- list(c(3, 4, 5, 8), c(2, 6, 9, 10), c(1, 7))
```

Following 3 forms will get the same outputs:

```
library(tidyverse)

# (1)
x %>% set_names(1:3) %>% stack %>% arrange(values) %>% select(ind)

# (2)
x %>% enframe %>% unnest %>% arrange(value) %>% select(name)

# (3)
x %>% (reshape2::melt) %>% arrange(value) %>% select(L1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also in `base`, something like this

```
L <- as.list(setNames( rep(1:length(lengths(l)), lengths(l)), unlist(l)))
# if wanted, sort it with
L[as.character(sort(as.integer(names(L))))]
# if wanted, unname with
unname(L)
```

with `l <- list(c(3, 4, 5, 8), c(2, 6, 9, 10), c(1, 7))`.

Or wrapped in a function

```
list_inside_out <- function (l, unName = TRUE) { 
  l2 <- lengths(l)
  out <- as.list(setNames(rep(1:length(l2), l2), unlist(l)))
  out <- out[as.character(sort(as.integer(names(out))))] 
  if (unName) return(unname(out))
  out
}
list_inside_out(l)
# [[1]]
# [1] 3
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `purrr`. `dat2` is the final output, an integer vector.

```
dat <- list(c(3, 4, 5, 8), c(2, 6, 9, 10), c(1, 7))

library(purrr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  imap(~set_names(.x, rep(.y, length(.x)))) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  sort() %>%
  names() %>%
  as.integer()
dat2
# [1] 3 2 1 1 1 2 3 1 2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using *`tidyverse`* and `purr::imap_dfr` we can create a  `tibble` with the values and indices side by side, `arrange` by value and `pull` the indices :

```
list_ <- list(c(3, 4, 5, 8), c(2, 6, 9, 10), c(1, 7))
library(tidyverse)
imap_dfr(list_,~tibble(.x,.y)) %>% arrange(.x) %>% pull(.y) %>% as.list

# [[1]]
# [1] 3
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 2
# 
# [[7]]
# [1] 3
# 
# [[8]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[9]]
# [1] 2
# 
# [[10]]
# [1] 2
```

Less pretty translated in base R (same output) :

```
with(
  as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,Map(cbind,a = list_, b =seq_along(list_)))),
  as.list(b[order(a)]))
```